# How to pass SurfaceHolder via AIDL?

Tags: android, surfaceview, here-api, aidl, surfaceholder

I have 2 separate Android app (apk).

App 1 creates `SurfaceView` inside it and should provide AIDL methods for other apps to obtain an instance of `SurfaceHolder` for such `SurfaceView`. So the other apps will be able to draw on that view, displayed inside app number 1.

I was able to transfer `Surface` itself via aidl easily, since it implements Parcelable interface.

```
// IMainService.aidl
package com.commonsware.cwac.preso.demo.service;
import android.view.Surface;

interface IMainService {
    Surface getSurf();
}
```

But 3-rd party sdk need `SurfaceHolder` to draw on. So the question is - how can I create `SurfaceHolder` for a given `Surface` instance, or how can I transfer `SurfaceHolder` via AIDL. Is there any examples of how I can implement Parcelable for `SurfaceHolder`?

My use-case (if its matter): App 1 starts as a `Service` and draw UI on Presentation Screen. And I need a way to get another apps display Navigation Data via Nokia Here Mobile SDK inside app 1. I need `SurfaceHolder` in order to use [this](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoffscreenrenderer.html#topic-apiref__start-surfaceholder-offscreenrenderer-surfaceupdatedlistener) api.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try extending the SurfaceHolder class and implement parcelabale

Comment: thanks, but SurfaceHolder is an interface...so...how can we make it parcelable? or maybe how to create it from given surface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a while, finally create a solution that works well with Here OffscreenRender API.

At one app I create SurfaceHolder and this app provide AIDL (see at the post above). With this AIDL I was able to correctly send Surface object and then, on app 2 side, make SurfaceHolder from it.

```
public class MySurfaceHolder implements SurfaceHolder {

private Surface surface;
private Rect rect;

MySurfaceHolder(Surface surface, Rect rect) {
    this.surface = surface;
    this.rect = rect;
}

///....

@Override
public Canvas lockCanvas() {
    return surface.lockCanvas(this.rect);
}

@Override
public Canvas lockCanvas(Rect rect) {
    return surface.lockCanvas(rect);
}

@Override
public void unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas canvas) {
    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}

@Override
public Rect getSurfaceFrame() {
    return rect;
}

@Override
public Surface getSurface() {
    return surface;
}
}
```

Basically, its my own SurfaceHolder, which get initialized by my own, instead of system. This approach need extend AIDL to be able to request Rect sizes, as well.

Hope that will be helpful for someone.